# Cypher relationships disconnected from nodes (pointing to nothing). Variable names wrong?

Tags: cypher

I'm expecting this script

```
// $ cd ~/Documents/neo4j-community-2.2.5/bin
// $ ./neo4j-shell -file ~/Documents/neo4j_input/neo4j_queries.txt    

//Purge
MATCH ()-[r]-() DELETE r;
MATCH (n) DELETE n;    

CREATE (p1:Person { first_name: "Apple", age: 9 });
CREATE (p2:Person { first_name: "Bear", age: 44 });    

CREATE (p2)-[x:ISPARENTOF]->(p1);
CREATE (p1)-[x2:ISCHILDOF]->(p2);
```

to look like this, with the relationships pointing from each person to the other:

```
     -ISCHILDOF->
(p1)             (p2)
    <-ISPARENTOF-
```

But instead the relationships are pointing to thin air. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers are only relevant within the scope of the query. You're executing separate queries.

```
CREATE (p1:Person { first_name: "Apple", age: 9 });
CREATE (p2:Person { first_name: "Bear", age: 44 });    

CREATE (p2)-[x:ISPARENTOF]->(p1);
CREATE (p1)-[x2:ISCHILDOF]->(p2);
```

In the 3rd and 4th queries, `p1` and `p2` are not bound to anything. You're creating nodes with no labels and no properties. You just need to remove the semicolons so that it's one query.

```
CREATE (p1:Person { first_name: "Apple", age: 9 })
CREATE (p2:Person { first_name: "Bear", age: 44 })

CREATE (p2)-[x:ISPARENTOF]->(p1)
CREATE (p1)-[x2:ISCHILDOF]->(p2);
```

In this query, `p1` and `p2` are bound when they're created at lines 1 and 2 respectively and used again at lines 4 and 5.